# How to make setup.py copy data files and set environment variable to the installed data path

Tags: python, setup.py

I am making a Python module (a wrapper for a C library) where I have some data files that needs to be installed for the package to work (coefficients for a magnetic field model). Additionally, after installation, an enviroment variable needs to be set to the folder where the data files ended up (or else the C library won't work).

I think I have managed to install the data files by using a manifest file and `include_package_data=True` (the files correctly end up in the directory where the package is installed, though if there are better ways I'm all ears). However I am stuck on the environment variable part.

1. How can I get (in setup.py) the directory to which the package was installed?
2. How can I reliably set a permanent environment variable in setup.py across all platforms?
3. Would a possible work-around be to set the environment variable at runtime whenever the package is imported? To find the directory I can use `__file__` in `__init.py__` and work my way from there, and the enviromnent variables don't have to stick. However, I'm not sure the C extension would have access to the environment variable defined through the Python wrapper. Would it?

Comment: I know off the bat that point 2) is not possible. You need to instruct users to do it themselves or provide an init / bootstrap scripts, which set the environment variables, for different platforms. Furhermore environment variables are a property of a process, so any code inside the process should see the set environment variables. If the C code caches the environment variables just set them before importing the C module.